# No value for id? Json php android java

Tags: java, php, android, json

Im kind of stumped now with this error as i am trying to get data pass from mysql server to my android studio via php however unsuccessful. Any idea why there is no value for id??

```
08-07 17:37:23.994 20693-20693/edu.nyp.reportify D/HttpAsyncTask: {"results":[{"id":"36","userid":"91","image":"reportImage\/579edd1aeb961 .png","reportType":"Crime","address":"Republic Crescent","latitude":"1.4436883","longitude":"103.786","details":"Car and bus accident","dateTime":"Aug 1, 2016 1:24:02 PM","status":"pending"},{"id":"39","userid":"91","image":"reportImage\/57a6d32ae45ff .png","reportType":"Accident","address":"Republic Crescent","latitude":"1.4436883","longitude":"103.786","details":"test","dateTime":"Aug 7, 2016 2:20:00 PM","status":"pending"}]}
08-07 17:37:23.995 20693-20693/edu.nyp.reportify W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for id


try {
                JSONArray resultArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                reports.clear();
                // Store all results into locations table layout
                for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {

                    //JSONObject resultObj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String reportid = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String userid = jsonObject.getString("userid");
                    String address = jsonObject.getString("address");
                    String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                    JSONObject ReportObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("resultObj");
                    reports.add(new ReportObj(reportid, reportType, address, status));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get the object form the array, and try to get the attributes from there

```
JSONObject tmpobject = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
String reportid = tmpobject.getString("id");
String userid = tmpobject.getString("userid");
String address = tmpobject.getString("address");
String status = tmpobject.getString("status");
```